# Initialize only one of the nested structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Say there are a struct 'Contact' which has two different structures in it.

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char lastName[36];
};

struct Numbers {
    char cell[15];
    char home[15];
};

struct Contact {
    struct Name name;
    struct Numbers numbers;
};
```

Now, I'm going to initialize all two nested structures(Name, Numbers) only by Contact variable in int main().

```
struct Contact contact[2] =
{ {"Jay", "Greene"}, {14, 15},
  {"Jay2", "Greene2"}, {16, 17} };

enter code here`printf("%s \n\n", contact[0].name.firstName); //output: Jay
```

Now, I'd like to initialize(remove) all the name of contact[0], but I'd like to KEEP numbers of contact[0].

This is the thing that I can't figure out. I can initialize each strings one by one, but I wanted to make every members in contact.name at one go.

I can initialize like this.

```
printf("%s \n\n", contact[0].name.firstName); //output: Jay

//initialization of all the members in contact[0].name, one by one.
contact[0].name.firstName[0] ='\0'; 
contact[0].name.lastName[0] ='\0';

printf("%s", contact[0].name.firstName); //no output here.
```

but if there are hundreds of members in Name construct, I can't do that like this way.

For example, I tried this.

```
contact[0].name = {0}; //first trial
contact[0].name = {{0}, {0}}; //second trial
```

Both occurs compile error.
If I'd like to initialize ALL of the nested structures, I could use memset. But here I need to initialize only contact.name, not the contact.numbers. Please help me.

Comment: What is your problem with `memset`?

Comment: You are not `//initialization of all the members in contact[0].name, one by one.`, you are setting each to *empty-string*. That is an assignment, not initialization. You only get one-shot at initialization, that is when you create the instance of `contact`, otherwise, you are not initializing, you are assigning. [C11 Standard (draft n1570) - 6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) Specifically [Note 19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19)

Answer (score 4):

You mix *initialization* with *assignment*.

This is initialization:

```
struct Contact contact[2] =
{ {"Jay", "Greene"}, {14, 15},
  {"Jay2", "Greene2"}, {16, 17} };
```

It is the combination of declaring a variable and giving it an initial value.

This is assignment:

```
contact[0].name = 0;
```

It assigns a new value to a variable that has already been declared.

With initialization of a structure you can specify the value of each member of the struct. With assignment you can only assign a value to one member at a time.

See also the link provided by David,  [C11 Standard (draft n1570) - 6.7.9 Initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) Specifically [Note 19](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19)

Comment: Grab the link from my comment if you like.

Comment: I tried that statement, but compile error happened.

Comment: That can't be. You do something else wrong. Note that the assignment must be in a function. It is a run-time statement and only functions run.